# Codevision AVR: accessing the arbitrary eeprom address for write

Tags: c, avr

I have a device made with ATtiny861, programmed with CodeVision AVR ver. 2.60.
I need to entirely erase the EEPROM (set it to FFs).
From the documentation I copy and paste the following code:

```
int eeprom *eepromp;
// some code...
main( void ) {
// some code...
for( eepromp=0; eepromp<=0x01FF; eepromp++ )
  *eepromp = 0xFF;
// some code...
```

But the compiller gives me the following error:
*Error: D:\work\projects\Radius(MPT)\control\code2\mpt.c(415): operand types 'eeprom int *' and 'int' are incompatible with the '<=' operator*

Documentation can be found at the address: https://instruct1.cit.cornell.edu/courses/ee476/codevisionC/cvavrman.pdf
The page containing the example: 84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that you can't compare `eeprom int` (the type of the `eepromp` variable) and plain `int` (the type of the literal `0x1ff`).

Either cast `eepromp` or the integer literal to the others type, or have an `int eeprom` variable with the end address that you compare to.

Comment: Thanks, @Joachim! It worked!!! Now the code in 'for' section is for( eepromp=0; eepromp<=(int eeprom*)0x01FF; eepromp++ )